# RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET while using SQL Server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database-connection

I have three different processes to crawl feeds, comments and reactions from Facebook. My code is working fine on 2 laptops. But in the 3rd laptop for comment crawling process, it shows this error.

> RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET

For other two processes, no such error occurs.

Here is my config.js file

```
var config = {
    dbconfig: {
        uid: '****',
        pass: '****',
        host: '****',
        db: '****',
        requestTimeout: 999999999,
    },
    serverPort: 5000,
    processInterval: 1000

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Nodejs version. I was using version 10.16.3 while other laptop where the problem was occurring was using 12.****. It worked fine when we changed the nodejs version.